# How do I refresh my ListView after the database changes?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to manage a simple list in an Android application. The contents of the list are maintained in a SQLite database. When the user selects and holds on a specific row, a context menu appears with a "Delete" option. When they select "Delete", the row is deleted from the database, but the view does not refresh. When I back out of the application and get back in, the appropriate row has been removed. So, I know the row is deleted, it's just the ListView that doesn't refresh.

Here are the relevant bits of code...

In the onCreate method...

```
SQLiteDatabase db = tasks.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, 
    new String[] { _ID, TITLE, DETAILS, }, 
    null, null, null, null, TITLE + " DESC");
startManagingCursor(cursor);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    cursor,
    new String[] {TITLE},
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1}
));
```

In the onContextItemSelected method...

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
case 0:
    SQLiteDatabase db = tasks.getWritableDatabase();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_ID=?", new String[] {adapter.getCursor().getString(0)});
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Not working, clears screen and doesn't reload
    return true;
}
return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `notifyDataSetChanged()` and call `requery()` on your `Cursor`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants) demonstrating this.

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the project code you referenced and discovered that I needed to store the Cursor with the class. I think I was copying it and passing it around, therefore making the requery() method ineffective. Once I made it a class-level variable, that did the trick.